# refresh div when other div is pressed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, refresh

I try to refresh div (Container) when the div (refresh) is pressed.

this is my `index.html.erb`:

```
<div id="Container">

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"> 
  <% @tasks_worker_todo.each do |task| %>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <div id="refresh"><%= best_in_place task, :done, :classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox,collection: %w[No Yes] %></div> | 
            <%= task.admin_mail %> | 
            <%= task.task %>
        </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<br><br>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <% @tasks_worker_done.each do |task| %>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">
            <%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: %w[No Yes] %> | 
            <%= task.admin_mail %> | 
            <%= task.task %>
        </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

</div>
```

and this is what I tried in my `application.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#refresh").bind("click", function() {
     $("#Container").reload()
   });
});
```

please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload a page by `location.reload()`, but you cannot reload a DIV. You need take use of iframe or preferably AJAX to fulfill your task.